# What does it mean to import a directory in Idris2?

Tags: idris, idris2

I usually see the `import` directive in Idris used on a `.idr` file. But in the [code here](https://github.com/edwinb/SPLV20/blob/master/TinyIdris-v2/src/Parser/Lexer/Common.idr), I see an instance of `import` used on a directory.

```
import public Text.Lexer
```

, where [Text.Lexer](https://github.com/edwinb/SPLV20/tree/master/TinyIdris-v2/src/Text/Lexer) is a directory containing only one file called `Core.idr`.

I couldn't find documentation for such usage. The [tutorial](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/modules.html) does not seem to say that one can import a directory, or what it means.

*Can someone help explain the meaning of the import directive here on the directory?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a *file* [`Text/Lexer.idr`](https://github.com/edwinb/SPLV20/blob/master/TinyIdris-v2/src/Text/Lexer.idr) in this repository. `import Text.Lexer` simply imports this single file. A directory cannot be imported.

It's common in Idris and related languages to have both a module `A` and some modules nested under `A`. The language imposes no relation; it's done purely for organizational purposes.